# Vue-router: transition doesn't affect background-image. Background-color is seen during the transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, transition

I have 2 routes where I have 2 different background-images. I added transition to the `<RouterView/>`, but the problem with is that I can see the `#4a195a` 0.2s  `background-color` that I set on `body { }` when I switch between routes. It looks ugly and instead I want to have a dark fade when I switch between routes. Also, it seems like router transitions don't affect the images, which means I manually need to add transition to each image. I'm not sure it should work like this. Please, help me to find a solution.

body styles:

```
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #4a195a;

}
```

routerview:

```
<RouterView #="{ Component }">
  <transition mode="out-in" name="fade">
  <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</RouterView>
```

transition styles:

```
.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
    transition: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you answer the question yourself -- remove the color from `body`? Also, it's highly recommended to make sure each component instance, wrapped in a transition, has a unique`key`, for example: `<component :is="something" :key="route.path">`

Comment: @Kalnode if I remove the color from `body`, I'm going to see a white flash when switching between routes. And, what if I want to have the same background-color on other routes? Also, thank you for mentioning the `key` attribute, do you think it's the same as `:key="$route.fullPath"` (in this case I don't need to import `useRoute()`?

Comment: @Kalnode also, it didn't fix the issue with no transition on background-image.

Comment: Keep the app background black, or whatever common bg color that works. For certain pages, if you need to, set a new background color; nothing wrong with that. It's hard to help you more without a functional demo. `:key` can be whatever you want, it just has to be unique. Yes, `$route` is a way people access route sometimes, sure.